# How to render new form from different view into application.html.erb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a feedback controller and view for it, I want to create a feedback link in my navigation bar, so how to import the new and create action for the feedback into my application controller ?. I found a gem render_component which does the same, but it has been decaprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content_for:

In your feeback view, you can add something like:

```
<% content_for :feedback_form do %>
  <%= FEEDBACK LINK GOES HERE %>
<% end %>
```

And in your application.html.erb you'll have something like:

```
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <%= yield %>

  ....

  <%= yield :feeback_form %>  
</head>
```

Comment: but what about the feedback controllers new and create action how do i get them into application controller ?

Comment: You wouldn't use a new action for this, since there's no separate page dedicated to the feedback form. And the create action you keep in the feedbacks controller.

Comment: actually when click on the link in the navigation bar it will open a new modal pop up

Comment: Got it. Still, since the HTML is ultimately on the application.html.erb, you wouldn't use a separate new action (unless the modal is contained an iframe, which it isn't).

Comment: no html is not on the same page, feedback is a different controller so its in the different view, so when i click on the link in the application.html.erb it should open the view in the feedbacks so it should render the new and create action of feedback into the application controller.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you're placing the form there, but it's just a link. In that case, you'll also have the new action in your Feedbacks controller.

Comment: I will need the new and create action of the feedback controller into my application controller